# Display an image when user sends a search form

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm pretty new to Angular and web in general and I'd like to display an image (check sign) when the user presses enter to send his search. I thought of using collapse but don't really know how to as I have no search button to send the request to. Sorry if this was already asked but I didn't find any real answers.

(Using Angular 6, HTML5, CSS3)

Thanks.

Comment: Update your question with your code (html and ts)

Answer (score 1):

In the Angular official documentation there is a separate section for user input. In there you can find how to work with key press events in Angular. [Find the link here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter).

What you have to do is something like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-key-up3',
  template: `
    <input (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)">
    <div *ngIf="showTick">your icon goes here</div>
  `
})
export class KeyUpComponent_v3 {
  value = '';
  showTick = false;
  onEnter(value: string) { this.showTick = true; }
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you or the answer, do i need to type my actual search box id in `<input #box (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)">` and can i put a web link  to the show the icon ?Do i need to make a new component especially for this ?

Comment: do i need to type my actual search box id? No .

can i put a web link to the show the icon ? Yes you can use a web link. or you can use any icon library like [font awesome](https://fontawesome.com/)

Comment: OK, last question how do i call this code in my actual page ?

Comment: You have a input field in your template right ?. Add an event handler to that input field as shown in the answer. And implement a method to handle the event in your ts file.